# Is there a standard for XML multi-signature?

Tags: xml, security, w3c, digital-signature

I have checked the XML Signature Syntax and Processing on W3C website,
however it says little about multi-signature.
Is there a standard or rule to create multi-signature on one single xml file?
Thank you

Example:(Consider Only same-file referencing)

Original xml

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>100</price>
  </item>
</root>
```

First A signs it with an enveloped signature

A Signed XML

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>100</price>
  </item>
  <Signature>this is Signature signed by A with Ref URL=""</Signature>
</root>
```

Now, B wants to sign the XML (containing A's signature)

B Signed XML

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>100</price>
  </item>
  <Signature>Signature A: this is Signature signed by A with Ref URL=""</Signature>
  <Signature>Signature B: this is Signature signed by B with Ref URL=""</Signature>
</root>
```

then when it comes to verifying, it becomes confusing...

for Signature A, while verifying, it sees

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>100</price>
  </item>
  <Signature>Signature B: this is Signature signed by B with Ref URL=""</Signature>
</root>
```

but what it actually signed is

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <price>100</price>
  </item>
</root>
```

(note that because of enveloped transform, one's signature node is removed while signing and verfying)
The same problem might be solved by treating Signature node as root when doing enveloping signature.
But if multiple references involved, it might become more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem in making several signatures over one set of nodes and including them into the same XML document using current XMLDSig standard. There are no special rules or standards needed.

With your sample, each signature is (should be) made not over "root", but over "item" node (or set of item nodes). Consequently signature B doesn't cover signature A as data to be signed.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I still quite confused. I'll edit my question to give an example that the additional signature might influence the preceding one.

Comment: Thank you! But what if it should be signed on root(like there's more then 1 item)? And signature B as well as the following signature in the future should have the ability to decide if the preceding signature nodes are signed by it selves individually. (situation like there's a D, who knows A and C, but can't recognize B and D, and D wants to sign the original content along with A and C's signatures). It seems that the user have to take care of these detail on one's own?

Comment: @iOSPadawan As I mentioned you can sign set of item nodes if you have many of them. In this case signatures are independent.

Comment: So, does it mean that to support multi-signature, signer has to take care of the format(especially the reference Xpath) him/herself? In the example, although it's a legal signature, the 1st signature shouldn't sign on ""(root), or the 2nd signature will invalidate the first one. And I'm a little confused about the enveloped signature over a set of nodes whose parent nodes are different, where should the enveloped signature node be placed? Thanks for helping

Comment: @iOSPadawan Yes, sure you would need to care about format and what exactly is signed. As for your second question - it should be asked separately. I guess XMLDSig authors just didn't count for such variant.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect the response come so fast. I guess maybe I should go to the mail list of xmlsec to see how they suggest to do. I appreciate for your answer. Really helps me a lot!